# Getting memory leaks when loading images from URl Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin

I am currently using Xamarin. to develop my android application
the problem I am having is when I load a bunch of images it takes a big piece of my stack memory and does not reset properly. So if the application starts on Activity A and you go to Activity B (loads it the images) I return to Activity A and go Back to B it crashes (out of memory issue). I have uploaded a demo application demonstrating the problem is am experiencing.

```
namespace imageLoader
{
[Activity (Label = "LoadImages")]           
public class LoadImages : Activity
{
    Bitmap image;
    List<PromotionClass> pro;
    PromotionAdapter proAdapter;
    RadListView radlist;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LoadImages);
        LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout)FindViewById   (Resource.Id.lin);
         radlist = new RadListView (this);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1, 
            LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);
        radlist.SetLayoutManager (gridLayoutManager);
        pro = new List<PromotionClass>();
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList ();
        a.Add ("http://apk.payment24.co.za/promotions/nov/Zappar.jpg");
        a.Add ("http://apk.payment24.co.za/promotions/nov/Valpre.jpg");
        a.Add ("http://apk.payment24.co.za/promotions/nov/Tropika.jpg");
        int dent = (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
        foreach (var url in a) {
            image = GlobalMethods.GetImageBitmapFromUrl(url.ToString(),dent);
            pro.Add(new PromotionClass("","",image));
        }
        proAdapter = new PromotionAdapter (pro, this);
        radlist.SetAdapter (proAdapter);
        line.AddView (radlist);
        // Create your application here
    }
    public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, typeof(LoadImages));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
        StartActivity (intent);
        this.Finish ();
    }
}
```

}

```
public  static Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url,int dens)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapScaled = null;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                // Create an image from the Byte Array
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                bitmapScaled = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, imageBitmap.Height * dens, imageBitmap.Width * dens, true);
                imageBitmap.Recycle();
            }
        }

        // Return the new Scaled image 
        return bitmapScaled;
    }
```

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzdvz9sdf91Ofmk0VER6MktQMUNpb25ybDU5ZDFZVmZoYXJNdTJZUVl1WlhhZHpHX1lNRHc&usp=sharing)

it also contains telerik dll files.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I would simply use UrlImageViewHelper to handle all of this for you: https://components.xamarin.com/view/urlimageviewhelper  It is an amazing library. Or check out picasso: https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso

Answer (score 0):

Store loaded bitmap into cache, so no need to reload bitmap.
Refer to https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code snippets you pasted here, another other issue could be that the "List()" each hold a reference to the "scaled" image - but these never seem to be released/recycled.

Have you tried essentially making PromotionClass disposable? Then inside the "OnDestroy()" method of the android activity, you can Dispose the "PromotionClass"'s which in turn can Recycle/Dispose the scaled down images.